# Duplicate Push Notifications Received when Integrating TalkJS in iOS App

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wkwebview, appdelegate

I am experiencing an issue with duplicate push notifications when integrating TalkJS into my iOS app. I have followed the necessary steps to configure push notifications and have successfully implemented TalkJS for chat functionality in my app. However, whenever a push notification is sent, I receive multiple duplicates of the same notification on the device.

**Here is an overview of my setup:**

1. I have integrated TalkJS SDK into my iOS app and have successfully
   set up chat functionality using the provided methods.
2. I have implemented push notification support using Apple Push
   Notification service (APNs) and have configured the necessary
   certificates and provisioning profiles.
3. I am using the window.talkSession.setPushRegistration() method
   provided by TalkJS to register the device for push notifications
   with the "apns" provider.

Despite following the documentation and making sure all the configurations are in place, I continue to receive multiple duplicate push notifications whenever a new message is received in the chat.

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

1. Ensured that the registerForRemoteNotifications() method is called
   correctly in my AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.
2. Verified that the push notification entitlements are correctly set
   up and associated with my app.
3. Tested on different devices but the issue persists.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue when integrating TalkJS in an iOS app? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this duplicate push notification problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error requesting authorization for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
        
        return true
```

[image]